# How to verify that self-signed certificate imported into keystore.jks works with truststore.jks?

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, openssl, keytool

### Introduction

Nowdays, it's common to setup SSL for communication between different internal micro-services.
In order to setup it, various steps are required.

My concrete example was that I was trying to setup secure communication for Kafka cluster, so that brokers communicate over SSL and that clients also use SSL when communicating with kafka brokers.

### Struggle

Usually, I would follow some tutorial steps just to get working example locally. But it can be hard to troubleshoot when it doesn't work. You don't know did you made mistake while generating root certificate or when creating keystore and truststore, or maybe something is wrong with your configuration.

Good thing is to read as much documentation before to try to understand what you are doing. And not just blindly follow some tutorial steps.
The thing is that it can be overwhelming to learn bunch of stuff all at once. Because you need to use various things: `openssl`, `keytool`, `Kafka` *(or whatever else)*

I've tried to search is there any existing tool or if `keytool` can be use directly to give it keystore, truststore and hostname and that result would be YES/NO if your those files are "compatible".

I know that there is possible to use
`openssl s_client -connect my-host:my-port`
But in order to use it you first need to spin up web server with your keystore.

## Question

How to ensure that among all configuration you need to do, that `keystore.jks` and `trustore.jks` that you've generated will work properly for some of your *hostname*?
So, that you can rule-out them as problematic and focus on another things that might cause your system not working.

---

#### Update

Some comments suggest other approaches:

- use `openssl` to start it with `s_server` and start it with `s_client`

  - **pros**: likely more reliable, better debug output
  - **cons**: if you only have `.jks` files you need to use `keytool` to convert them to `.p12`
- use `Keystore explorer` or `keytool -v -list ...` to inspect contents

  - this is manual work and it's not clear what values need to match in order to guarantee that communication will actually work between (`server` having `keystore.jks`) and (`client` having `truststore.jks`)

Comment: `openssl` can also be used to start a server (via `s_server` https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/s_server.html) that will be serving your certs. Combined with its debug capabilities, it is hands-down best tool for the job.

Comment: So, what would then take to do verification: **1)** convert `keystore.jks` to `keystore.p12`; **2)** convert `truststore.jks` to `truststore.p12`; **3)** start `openssl` with `s_server` given `keystore.p12`; **4)** start `openssl` with `s_client` given `truststore.p12` to connect on server started at *3)* ?

Comment: If you didn't use `openssl` to generate your certs, and have them in Java format (.jks) then yes.

Answer (score 1):

I've create simple small program to verify keystore.jks against trustore.jks.
It's a simple java program which will open ssl socket and then run client to try to connect to this socket and exchange some data.

Here is [gist](https://gist.github.com/antonio-tomac/24950a3852f52ec4ecb7e3e7ad16779e) I've created to share it.

You can compile it simply with:

```
javac KeyTest.java
```

Run it with:

```
java KeyTest \
   -k path-to-keystore.jks -kp keystore-password \
   -t path-to-truststore.jks -tp truststore-password \
   -h localhost -p 443
```

**NOTES**:

- For `-h` you need to specify host (common name CN) you used when creating keystore (eg. CN=localhost)
- You need to run it this host because client will try to connect to it, alternative is to run it somewhere else but then you can add `127.0.0.1 my.example.host.com` into `/etc/hosts` to direct DNS resolution to this same machine

Comment: Personally, I use keystore explorer

Comment: I've also installed keystore explorer few days ago but I couldn't figure out what exactly do I need to check when having opened keystore and truststore. It's somewhat hard to compare signatures and keys manually by looking with eyes.